# How do I incorporate one function into another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to define two separate functions `z(x, mu, c)` and `landau(x, A, mu, c)`.
`z = (x-mu)/c`  and  `landau = 1.64872*A*np.exp(-0.5(z+np.exp(-z)))`

As they share variables I have tried to define `z` inside the definition of `landau` as a function itself and not as a function. Also, I have tried to define `z` as a function outside the definition of `landau`. However, nothing I try seems to work. Either python tells me `"'float' object is not callable"` or `"bad operant type for unary -: 'function'"`. Is there a quick fix for this?

`landau(1,1,1,1)` should give an answer that's roughly equal to 1

```
def landau(x, A, mu, c):    # Functie Landau met variabelen x, A, c en mu
# A  = amplitude
# c  = schaalparameter
# mu = positieparameter
def z(x, mu, c):
    return (x-mu)/c
return 1.64872*A*np.exp(-0.5(z(x, mu, c)+np.exp(-z(x, mu, c))))
```

Comment: I suggest you start with defining two separate functions. Try to call them and see what happens. You can update this question with your entire code, plus full error tracebacks.

Comment: Took a quick look and you're missing an operator between `-0.5` and the open parenthesis in `-0.5(z...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a * in `-0.5 * (z(x`.  At least I'm assuming it's supposed to be a multiplication.

```
import numpy as np

def landau(x, A, mu, c):    # Functie Landau met variabelen x, A, c en mu
     # A  = amplitude
     # c  = schaalparameter
     # mu = positieparameter
     return 1.64872 * A * np.exp(-0.5 * (z(x, mu, c) + np.exp(-z(x, mu, c))))

def z(x, mu, c):
     return (x - mu) / c
     
landau(1, 1, 1, 1)
0.9999992292814129
```

Comment: btw, nothing wrong with having `z` defined in `landau` like you did. not sure if one way or the other is the preferred style.